# How to get the int for enum value in Enumeration

Tags: c#, enums, enumeration

If I had the value : "dog" and the enumeration:

```
public enum Animals
{
  dog = 0 ,
  cat = 1 ,
  rat = 2
}
```

how could I get 0 for the value "dog" from Animals ?

EDIT:

I am wondering if there is index like acces. More commonn : how can I get the integer for string value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question "how can I get the integer for string value":

To convert from a string into an enum, and then convert the resulting enum to an int, you can do this:

```
public enum Animals
{
    dog = 0,
    cat = 1,
    rat = 2
}

...

Animals answer;

if (Enum.TryParse("CAT", true, out answer))
{
    int value = (int) answer;
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

By the way, normal enum naming convention dictates that you should not pluralize your enum name unless it represents flag values (powers of two) where multiple bits can be set - so you should call it `Animal`, not `Animals`.

Answer (score 7):

Just cast your enum value to integer:

```
Animals animal = Animals.dog;
int value = (int)animal; // 0
```

EDIT: if it turns out that you have name of enum value, then parse enum value and cast it to integer:

```
int value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Animals), "dog");
```

Comment: He has a string not enum.

Comment: @TuTran can you that he edited question?

Comment: I think OP's question is clear: `how could I get 0 for the value "dog"`

Comment: @TuTran as you can see above, it's not clear

Answer (score 5):

You can either [cast it to Int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), or iterate over all values using the [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) Method which retrieves an array of the values of the constants in a specified enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

What about: `var r = (int)Animals.dog`

Comment: Need to parse `"dog"` to `Animals.dog` first

Comment: @Tu Tran - really, are you sure? I don't agree... Try it yourself.

Comment: Absolutely sure. See the answer of Matthew Watson, I totally agree with him.

Comment: @Tu Tran - please copy and paste my code and try it yourself.

Comment: Because the question has been edited (as Sergey Berezovskiy noticed), I think you should check the question again.